# Compute $\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question:** Compute this integral
$$\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx$$

**My Approach:**

$$\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx$$
$$=\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\times \frac{{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}}{{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}}~dx$$
$$\int\frac{(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+5x})}{x^2+5x-36}~dx~~- \underbrace {~\int\frac{(6x+12)}{x^2+5x-36}~dx~}_{\text{This one I know how to deal with} }$$
$$\text{Now:} ~\int\frac{(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+5x})}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(2x+5-1)(\sqrt{x^2+5x})}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(2x+5)(\sqrt{x^2+5x})}{x^2+5x-36}~dx~~- \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+5x})}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$
$$\Big( \text{Let} ~ x^2+5x=t \implies (2x+5)~dx = dt \Big)$$
$$ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{t-36}~dt}_{\text{I can deal with this}} ~~- \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$

Now I'm stuck. I am unable to calculate: $$ \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$

**P.S.:** I am high school student so please try to use elementary integrals only; i.e. integration by parts and substitution. I don't know how to use complex numbers in integration, multiple integrals, error function, etc. (I don't know if it can be used here or not, just clarifying.)

As answered by @Kanwaljit Singh: Finally I have to compute:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}$$

But if I was able to compute it, I would have done it in the very first step, id est ;

$$\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx = 
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x+5-1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx
\\ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx ~- \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx
\\ \Big( \text{Let} ~ x^2+5x=t \implies (2x+5)~dx = dt \Big)
\\ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{t+6}~dt}_{\text{Doable}} ~-~\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx
\\ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx $$

Reached to a similar step by a short path. But how do I compute this one?

Comment: +1 for a well written question. It is worth us knowing what you mean by "elementary integrals"? Is integration by substitution a technique which you have been taught?

Comment: As $x^2+5x=\dfrac{(2x+5)^2-5^2}4,$ let $2x+5=5\sec t$

Comment: @MattS Yes, I know about Integration by parts and substitution also, but nothing about complex numbers in integrals or multiple  integrals(that's why I said elementary)

Comment: My question is to make sure that the integral you are supposed to solve really is $\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6} ~dx$ and not $\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}} ~dx$, and that this is not a typo caused by transcribing a badly handwritten expression. I'm asking because of course $x^2+5x+6 = (x+2)(x+3)$, which would make this slightly easier to integrate.

Comment: @shoover, Definitely No. It is printed question.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%2B2)%2F((x%5E2%2B5x)%5E(1%2F2)%2B6)

Comment: Hello Little Ramanujan! interesting integral. :D
I am not sure if my Answer is the optimal solution,  Nonetheless It has made me fun to solve these Integral.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$I = \int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx$$
$$\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x+4)}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+ 5 -1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx$$
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx}_{I_1}\, -\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx}_{I_2}$$

**The first integral $I_1$**
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx$$
Set $u = x^2+5x \implies \frac{du}{dx} = 2x + 5 \iff dx = \frac{du}{(2x + 5)}$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}+6}\, du $$
Set $t =\sqrt{u} \implies \frac{dt}{du} =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} = \frac{1}{2t} \iff du = 2t\,dt$
$$\int\frac{t}{t + 6}\, dt = \int\left(1 - \frac{6}{t + 6}\right) \, dt = t - 6\log(t +6) + C$$
Substitute back $t = \sqrt{u} = \sqrt{x^2+5x}$

> $$I_1 = \sqrt{x^2+5x} - 6\log(\sqrt{x^2+5x} + 6) + C$$

**The second integral $I_2$**
$$I_2 = -\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}\, dx$$
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6} \,\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}\, dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}{x^2+5x -36}\, dx$$
$$\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x^2+5x -36}\, dx}_{i_1} + \underbrace{3\int\frac{1}{x^2+5x -36}\, dx}_{i_2}$$
**We solved $i_2$**
$$3\int\frac{1}{x^2+5x -36}\, dx $$
$$3\int\frac{1}{(x+9)(x-4)}\, dx$$
$$3\int\frac{1}{13(x-4)}-\frac{1}{13(x+9)}\, dx$$
$$\frac{3}{13}\left( \int\frac{1}{x-4}\, dx\ - \int\frac{1}{x+9}\, dx\right) $$

> $$i_2 = \frac{3}{13}\left( \log(x-4) - \log(x+9) \right) +C$$

**We solved $i_1$**
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x^2+5x -36}\, dx$$
Let $x^2+5x = \left(x + \frac{5}{2}  \right)^2 - \frac{25}{4}$ then 
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{2}  \right)^2 - \left(\frac{5}{2}  \right)^2}}{\left(x + \frac{5}{2}  \right)^2  - \frac{169}{4}}\, dx = $$
we defeined $a = \frac{5}{2}$ and $u = x + \frac{5}{2}  \implies dx  = du $
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2 - a^2}}{u^2 - \left( \frac{13}{2} \right)^2 }\, du$$
By Trigonometric Substitution

[image]

$$\text{Let }\sqrt{u^2 - a^2} = \sqrt{a\sec^2\varTheta - a^2} = \sqrt{a^2(\sec^2\varTheta - 1)} = \sqrt{a^2\tan^2\varTheta} = a\tan\varTheta $$
$$\therefore\, u = a\sec\varTheta \implies du = a\sec\varTheta \tan\varTheta d\varTheta$$
With these substitutions, Thus the integral takes the form
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{a\tan\varTheta}{\left(  a\sec\varTheta\right) ^2 - \left( \frac{13}{2} \right)^2}\, a\sec\varTheta \tan\varTheta\, d\varTheta$$
Since $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ then we have
$$u = a\frac{1}{\cos} \implies du = a\frac{\sin\varTheta}{\cos^2\varTheta} d\varTheta$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{\left( a\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}\right)^2 - a^2}}{\left( a\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}\right) ^2 - \left( \frac{13}{2} \right)^2 }\, a\frac{\sin\varTheta}{\cos^2\varTheta} d\varTheta$$
$$-\frac{a}{2}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{ a^2\left(\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}\right)^2 - a^2}}{\cos^2\varTheta\left(  a^2\left(\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}\right)^2 - \left( \frac{13}{2} \right)^2 \right) }\, d\varTheta$$
$$-\frac{a^2}{2}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{\cos^2\varTheta\left( a^2\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - \left( \frac{13}{2} \right)^2 \right) }\, d\varTheta$$
Back $a = \frac{5}{2}$  substitution 
$$-\frac{25}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{\cos^2\varTheta\left( \frac{25}{4}\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - \frac{169}{4} \right) }\, d\varTheta = -\frac{25}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{\cos^2\varTheta\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{25}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 169 \right) }\, d\varTheta = -\frac{25}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{\cos^2\varTheta\frac{1}{4\cos^2\varTheta}\left(25 - 169\cos^2\varTheta \right) }\, d\varTheta$$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{25 - 169\cos^2\varTheta }\, d\varTheta$$
Since $\cos^2(x) = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\varTheta} - 1 }}{\sin^2\varTheta\left( \frac{25}{\sin^2\varTheta} - \frac{169}{\tan^2\varTheta}\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
Let $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \implies \tan^2(x) + 1 = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} +1 = \frac{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$
then $\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = \tan(x) +1$ and $\frac{1}{tan^2(x) +1} = \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ we have
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\sqrt{\tan^2\varTheta}}{\sin^2\varTheta\left( \frac{25}{\sin^2\varTheta} - \frac{169}{\sin^2\varTheta}+ 169\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\sin\varTheta\tan\varTheta}{\sin^2\varTheta\left( \frac{-144}{\sin^2\varTheta} + 169\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
Let $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\sin^2\varTheta\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}}{-\sin^2\varTheta\left( \frac{144}{\sin^2\varTheta} - 169\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
$$\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta}}{\left( \frac{144}{\sin^2\varTheta} - 169\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
$$\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{1}{\frac{\cos\varTheta}{\sin^2\varTheta}  \left( 144 - 169\frac{1}{\sin^2\varTheta}\right)  }\, d\varTheta$$
Set 
$$w = \frac{1}{\sin \varTheta} \implies dw = -\frac{\cos\vartheta}{\sin^2\varTheta}$$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{1}{144 - 169w^2  }\, wd$$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{1}{(12 + 13w)(12 - 13w)}\, wd$$
$$-\frac{100}{8}\int\frac{1}{24(12 + 13w)}-\frac{1}{24(13w - 12)}\, wd$$
$$-\frac{25}{48}\left( \int\frac{1}{12 + 13w}\, wd-\int\frac{1}{13w - 12}\, wd\right) $$
$$-\frac{25}{48}\left( \log(12 + 13w) - \log(13w - 12)\right) +C$$
Now, back substitute to get
$$u = \frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{\cos\varTheta} \implies \cos\varTheta = \frac{5}{2u}$$
Let $\sin(x) = \sqrt{1- \cos^2(x)}$
$$\sin\varTheta = \sqrt{1- \cos^2\varTheta} = \sqrt{1- \left( \frac{5}{2u}\right) ^2} = \frac{1}{2u}\sqrt{4u^2 - 25}$$
$$w = \frac{1}{\sin \varTheta} = \frac{2u}{\sqrt{4u^2 - 25}}$$
$$u = x + \frac{5}{2}$$
$$w = \frac{2\left( x + \frac{5}{2}\right) }{\sqrt{4\left( x + \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 - 25}} = \frac{2x + 5}{\sqrt{4(x^2 + 5x + \frac{25}{4}) - 25} } = \frac{2x + 5}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 5x}}$$
Also

> $$i_1 = -\frac{25}{48}\left( \log\left( 12 + 13\frac{2x + 5}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 5x}}\right)  - \log\left( 13\frac{2x + 5}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 5x}} - 12\right) \right) +C$$

**The Solution:**
$$ I = I_1 + i_1 + i_2$$
Set $t = x^2 + x5$

> $$I = 
> \sqrt{t} - 6\log(\sqrt{t} + 6)    
> -\frac{25}{48}\left( \log\left( 12 + 13\frac{2x + 5}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)  - \log\left( 13\frac{2x + 5}{2\sqrt{t}} - 12\right) \right)
> + \frac{3}{13}\left( \log(x-4) - \log(x+9) \right) + C$$

Comment: I salute you to keep patience while writing such a long answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

$$ \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x^2+5x-36}~dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6-6}{(\sqrt{x^2+5x})^2-6^2}~dx$$

$=\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}{(\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6)(\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6)} - \int \frac{6}{x^2+5x-36} ~dx$

$$=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6} - \int \frac{6}{x^2+5x-36} ~dx$$

Hope you can proceed further.

Comment: How to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6}$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare It's doable but still quite messy. Are you expected to be able to do this integral 'by hand'?

Comment: @StackTD I didn't what do you mean 'by hand' integration?

Comment: @JaideepKhare I mean _manually_ (pencil & paper), as opposed to using (computer) software. As I said: it's possible, but messy; which made me wonder if you are supposed to do this _by hand_.

Comment: @JaideepKhare its little messy to solve further. I am trying to solve it further. Give me some time. If you are able to solve it yourself. Please post here.

Comment: @StackTD , Yes. It is a question from sample paper of a competitive exam.If it is too long to type, you can answer by posting an image of hand-written solution.It will work for me.

Comment: @JaideepKhare [Integral Calculator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) will give you a manual, step-by-step based solution - not necessarily the most efficient method, but one you should be able to do with the standard techniques.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I am unable to do it further, that's why I asked (See my edit). But if I come to know by any other means, I will definitely post it.

Comment: @StackTD I have already tried that website, but it is too loooong to do it in any exam. So I suppose, there might be a short solution to do in a competitive exam.

Comment: Can you show us the pic of original question because I think if its competitive exam question then its not this much lengthy. And if in book answer is also available please post it too.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Done. I don't have an answer. It was sent to me by my friend. He also doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Introduce the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

Let $u=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x}$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{5}{u^2-1}$

$dx=-\dfrac{10u}{(u^2-1)^2}~du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx$

$=-\int\dfrac{\dfrac{5}{u^2-1}+2}{\dfrac{5u}{u^2-1}+6}\dfrac{10u}{(u^2-1)^2}~du$

$=-\int\dfrac{(2u^2+3)10u}{(6u^2+5u-6)(u^2-1)^2}~du$

$=-\int\dfrac{(2u^2+3)10u}{(3u-2)(2u+3)(u+1)^2(u-1)^2}~du$

$=\int\left(-\dfrac{5}{2(u+1)^2}-\dfrac{5}{2(u-1)^2}+\dfrac{11}{2(u+1)}+\dfrac{13}{2(u-1)}-\dfrac{144}{13(2u+3)}-\dfrac{252}{13(3u-2)}\right)~du$ (according to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-((2u%5E2%2B3)10u)%2F((3u-2)(2u%2B3)(u%2B1)%5E2(u-1)%5E2))

$=\dfrac{5}{2(u+1)}+\dfrac{5}{2(u-1)}+\dfrac{11\ln(u+1)}{2}+\dfrac{13\ln(u-1)}{2}-\dfrac{72\ln(2u+3)}{13}-\dfrac{84\ln(3u-2)}{13}+C$

$=\dfrac{5u}{u^2-1}+\dfrac{11\ln(u+1)}{2}+\dfrac{13\ln(u-1)}{2}-\dfrac{72\ln(2u+3)}{13}-\dfrac{84\ln(3u-2)}{13}+C$

$=\sqrt{x^2+5x}+\dfrac{11}{2}\ln\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x}+\dfrac{13}{2}\ln\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x}{x}-\dfrac{72}{13}\ln\dfrac{3x+2\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{x}-\dfrac{84}{13}\ln\dfrac{3\sqrt{x^2+5x}-2x}{x}+C$

Comment: Can you explain how to complete it further?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x+\frac52=\frac52\sec t$

\begin{align}
I=&\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+6}~dx\\
=& \ \int \frac{5(5\sec t -1)\sec t\tan t}{24+10\tan t}\ dt\\
= &\int \frac{25\tan t\sec^2t}{24+10\tan t}
-\frac12\sec t +\frac{6\sec t}{12+5\tan t}\  dt
\end{align}
where $\int \sec t\ dt=\tanh^{-1}(\sin t)$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{25\tan t\sec^2t}{24+10\tan t}\ dt
=\frac52\tan t-6\ln(12+5\tan t)\\
&\int \frac{6\sec t}{12+5\tan t}\  dt =\frac1{13}\tanh^{-1}\frac{12\sin t-5\cos t}{13}\\
\end{align}
After back-substitution
$$I=\sqrt{x^2+5x}-6\ln\left( \sqrt{x^2+5x}+6\right)
-\frac12\tanh^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+5x}}{2x+5}\\
+\frac6{13}\tanh^{-1}\frac{24 \sqrt{x^2+5x}-25}{13(2x+5)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

all of these answers are so stupendously complicated yo! here's a much better method:
as stated, we need to deal with integral of 1/(sqrt(x^2+5x)+6)
write x^2+5x= (x+5/2)^2 - (5/2)^2
now substitute x+5/2 = 5y/2
now, our main focus after taking the constants out becomes the integral of 
1/(sqrt(y^2 - 1) + 12/5)
put arcsecy= z or y= secz so integral after getting rid of constants is
secz.tanz/(tanz + a) where a = 12/5.
now, here comes the genius step:
secz.tanz/(tanz + a)= secz - asecz/(tanz + a). else this prob was **extremely** hard. Obviously we already know integral of secz.
For secz/(tanz + a), write it as 1/(sinz + acosz). now this is the standard form that can be solved by either of the 2 methods:

1. Let 1= rcosq and a= rsinq and hence forming a sine term in the denominator.
2. Or even better, go for u= tan(z/2) substitution (also referred to as the universal substitution) and you will get an easy standard rational function that even a 4 yo can integrate!